# How do I get the current user's name from Game Center

Tags: ios, game-center

When the authenticated handler fires on return from Game Center, the local player is listed with displayName = "Me" and the alias is the player's username. However I'd like to display the user's full name instead, so want the actual displayName, not "Me".

Is there a way of specifying I want the full name, not "Me"?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer showing the alias, especially when matching with random players but both the alias and the displayName require that the player's authentication be complete to start returning their appropriate values.

In order for the authentication process to start, you have to set the local player's authentication handler.  Simply setting it starts the process and the method will be called within a few seconds.   After that the local player's alias and displayName should be the right ones.

for example:

```
 class YourGameCenterManager:GKGameCenterControllerDelegate,
                    GKLocalPlayerListener
 {
   var localGCAccount: GKLocalPlayer!
   var active               = false

   init()
   { 
     localGCAccount     = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
     localGCAccount?.authenticateHandler = gameCenterAuthentication
   }

   func gameCenterAuthentication(gameCenterVC :UIViewController?, err:NSError?)
   {    
      if gameCenterVC != nil
      {       
        // Game center wants to display a sign-on view ...
        // note: I personally never got this to actually happen
      }
      else if localGCAccount?.authenticated ?? false
      {
         if not(active)
         {
           active = true
           localGCAccount?.unregisterAllListeners()
           localGCAccount?.registerListener(self) 

           // ... whatever else you need to do when Game Center is ready
           // at this point localGCAccount's alias and displayName should be ok
         }
      }
      else if active
      {   
        //... Game Center just went bad ... do what you have to to to handle it    
        active = false      
      }         
   }
```